# appium , selenium.SessionNotCreatedException Error

Tags: java, selenium, appium, appium-android

I tried to launch appium first test but I got an error however some fields are not blank.
My error log is that:

**

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could
>   not be created. Details: The desiredCapabilities object was not valid
>   for the following reason(s):  deviceName can't be blank, (WARNING: The
>   server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or
>   timeout: 393 milliseconds Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision:
>   'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z' System info: host:
>   'ASUS-BILGISAYAR', ip: '192.168.1.103', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch:
>   'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_151' Driver info:
>   driver.version: AndroidDriver     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$24(ProtocolHandshake.java:359)
>     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:362)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:136)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:89)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:646)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:255)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:237)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:138)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:87)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:111)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:72)
>     at com.enuygun.test.StartApplication.main(StartApplication.java:19)

**
My codes are as in the below:

```
package com.enuygun.test;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;



public class StartApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android();
            WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/Apps/Amazon/");
            File app = new File(appDir, "in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping.apk");


            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Micromax A311");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
            capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping");
            capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity");


            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            driver.quit();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are instantiating your driver before you are setting your desired capabilities, so your capabilities object is blank.  Move your line to create a new driver after your desired capabilities properties are being set.